# How to replace below line in bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

**Original Line -**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Dbname', {useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false })
```

**Need to replace -**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:Password@host1.localhost.com:27017,host2.localhost.com:27017,host3.localhost.com:27017/DBname?authSource=admin&w=1&replicaSet=replicaname&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=true',{useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false })
```

while we try to replace this line through below command

```
sed -i 's+mongodb://localhost/Dbname+mongodb://username:Password@host1.localhost.com:27017,host2.localhost.com:27017,host3.localhost.com:27017/DBname?authSource=admin\\\&w=\\\1&replicaSet=replicaname&readPreference=secondaryPreferred\\&retryWrites=true/g' app.js
```

We are getting different output.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:Password@host1.localhost.com:27017,host2.localhost.com:27017,host3.localhost.com:27017/DBname?authSource=admin\mongodb://localhost/Dbnamew=1\mongodb://localhost/DbnamereplicaSet=replicaname\mongodb://localhost/DbnamereadPreference=secondaryPreferred\mongodb://localhost/DbnameretryWrites=true', {useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false })
```

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework problem.

Comment: while we try to replace this line through below command sed -i 's+mongodb://localhost/Password+mongodb://username:Password@host1.localhost.com:27017,host2.localhost.com:27017,host3.localhost.com:27017/DBname?authSource=admin\\\&w=\\\1&replicaSet=replicaname&readPreference=secondaryPreferred\\&retryWrites=true/g' app.js

Comment: We are getting different output. mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:Password@host1.localhost.com:27017,host2.localhost.com:27017,host3.localhost.com:27017/DBname?authSource=admin\mongodb://localhost/Passwordw=1\mongodb://localhost/PasswordreplicaSet=replicaname\mongodb://localhost/PasswordreadPreference=secondaryPreferred\mongodb://localhost/PasswordretryWrites=true', {useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false })

Comment: Please try to find a minimal representation of the issue. I don't want to scroll the whole string to find what is wrong.

Comment: Also, your input does not match your `sed`. Check Dbname vs Password.

Comment: @pLumo Dbnamevs Password has been corrected in the Post now.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing two ways of achieving your goal.
The tricky part is how to deal with `&` as a string literal ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172002/awk-gsub-ampersands-and-unexpected-expansion), [ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Gory-Details.html)).
I assume file `test.txt` contains your base string.

```
awk -v old="mongodb://localhost/Dbname" -v new="mongodb://username:Password@host1.localhost.com:27017,host2.localhost.com:27017,host3.localhost.com:27017/DBname?authSource=admin&w=1&replicaSet=replicaname&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=true" 's=index($0,old){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} 1' test.txt 

awk -v old="mongodb://localhost/Dbname" '{ gsub(old, "mongodb://username:Password@host1.localhost.com:27017,host2.localhost.com:27017,host3.localhost.com:27017/DBname?authSource=admin\\&w=1\\&replicaSet=replicaname\\&readPreference=secondaryPreferred\\&retryWrites=true") ; print $0 }' test.txt
```

And a more flexible version, which allows for other search-for strings.
Here, the tricky part is how to deal with `'` as a field separator for `awk` ([ref](https://superuser.com/questions/470846/how-to-use-awk-separator-of-single-quote)).

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "'\''" } ; { gsub($2, "mongodb://username:Password@host1.localhost.com:27017,host2.localhost.com:27017,host3.localhost.com:27017/DBname?authSource=admin\\&w=1\\&replicaSet=replicaname\\&readPreference=secondaryPreferred\\&retryWrites=true") ; print $0 }' test.txt
```